# How can I display an image and its url side by side in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to display an image and the url of it side by side.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are u Displaying image directly from internet?

Answer (score 1):

*To be honest, you question is not a good one and doesn't really fit the requirements here. Anyway, as you seem to be a totally beginner and because thats your first question here (welcome!), I will provde some infos.*

Two kind of views do you need. The first one will be an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) where you can display your image with. The second one can be a simple [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) where you can set the text to the URL.

To make them displayed side by side, you need a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with the orientation set to horizontal. Inside that layout you can place the ImageView and than the TextView. Both views should have the layout_width set to `wrap_content` and the layout_weight to `1`.

In your activity you can then set the image to the ImageView and the URL to the TextView.

Here is the simple xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
    android:text="dummytext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

A [LinearLayout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) can be found in the official docs where a [lot of views and layouts are shown and explained](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html).